# VSCode does not copy all lines of a log file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a log with 45,589 lines and when I copy/paste all content it in a new tab, only 29,632 lines are pasted.

Any ideas why this happens? Is there a setting to extent the line limit in VSCode?

Comment: What if you try pasting into something else, like a new text file? Does everything copy over?

Comment: So I copied & pasted hello world 50,000 times in a log file. I was going to post a screen shot, but I don't want to do it in an answer. I doubled it to 100,000 lines, and it copy & pastes fine for me, from one file to the next.

Comment: Its probably due to formatting